# Applying Neumann BC on 2D Diffusion Equation on Python using Finite-Difference Method

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, pde, finite-difference

Given a diffusion equation:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = c \Big(\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial y^2} \Big)$$

with homogeneous Neumann Boundary Condition

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \nu} = 0,$$

where $\nu$ is an outward direction on the boundary.

I am trying to plot the pde using fdm on python. However, when I tried to plot the code that I am using, it creates
this image

[image]

in which was not an image I was expecting. I am expecting that the resulting image would diffuse equally throughout the domain but the created image is somehow attracted to the right boundary. Can you help me spot an error in my code? Thank you for your attention.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.1
D = 0.6
dx = np.sqrt(D*dt/0.1)
dy = np.sqrt(D*dt/0.1)
t = np.arange(0, 100+dt, dt)
nt = len(t)
x = np.arange(-15, 15+dx, dx)
nx = len(x)
y = np.arange(-20, 20+dy, dy)
ny = len(y)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

S = np.zeros((nt,nx,ny))
S[0, nx//2, ny//2] = 100

for k in range(nt-1):
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                S_xx = 2*S[k,1,0] - 2*S[k,0,0]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,0,1] - 2*S[k,0,0]                
                
            elif i == 0 and (j > 0 and j < ny-1):
                S_xx = 2*S[k,1,j] - 2*S[k,0,j]
                S_yy = S[k,0,j+1] - 2*S[k,0,j] + S[k,0,j-1]                
                
            elif i == 0 and j == ny-1:
                S_xx = 2*S[k,1,-1] - 2*S[k,0,-1]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,0,-2] - 2*S[k,0,-1]
                
                
            elif (i > 0 and i < nx-1) and j == 0:
                S_xx = S[k,i+1,0] - 2*S[k,i,0] + S[k,i-1,0]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,i,1] - 2*S[k,i,0]
                
            elif (i > 0 and i < nx-1) and j == ny-1:
                S_xx = S[k,i+1,-1] - 2*S[k,i,-1] + S[k,i-1,-1]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,i,-2] - 2*S[k,i,-1]

            elif i == nx-1 and j == 0:
                S_xx = 2*S[k,-2,0] - 2*S[k,-1,0]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,-1,1] - 2*S[k,-1,0]
                
                
            elif i == nx-1 and (j > 0 and j < ny-1):
                S_xx = 2*S[k,-2,j] - 2*S[k,-1,j]
                S_yy = S[k,-1,j+1] - 2*S[k,-1,j] + S[k,-1,j-1]
                
            elif i == nx-1 and j == ny-1:
                S_xx = 2*S[k,-2,-1] - 2*S[k,-1,-1]
                S_yy = 2*S[k,-1,-2] - 2*S[k,-1,-1]
                
                
            else:
                S_xx = S[k,i+1,j] - 2*S[k,i,j] + S[k,i-1,j]
                S_yy = S[k,i,j+1] - 2*S[k,i,j] + S[k,i,j-1]
         
            S[k+1,i,j] = S[k,i,j] + D*dt*(S_xx/dx**2 + S_yy/dy**2)

plt.contourf(X, Y, S[-1].transpose())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does this asymmetry look in earlier stages? It could be the result of the slight asymmetry in positioning the middle point with the initial peak. // I would use `x = np.arange(-15, 15+0.5*dx, dx)` etc. in constructing the grid, this will be closer to the intended boundaries. Otherwise I see nothing wrong, except that the computation could be simplified using array slice operations.